# JavaScript recursive for nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I tried the following code and expected returns `14` but the result is `Nan`. I think this might be async issue but not sure how to solve it. Does anyone happen to know smarter way to address this issue ?

```
a = {key: "a", value: 1}          // 1
b = {key: "b", values: [a, a, a]} // 3
c = {key: "c", values: [a, a]}    // 2
d = {key: "d", values: [a, a, a]} // 3
e = {key: "e", values: [a, a]}    // 2
f = {key: "f", values: [a, a]}    // 2
g = {key: "g", values: [a]}       // 1

h = {key: "h", values: [a, b, c]} // 6
i = {key: "i", values: [d, e]}    // 5
j = {key: "i", values: [f, g]}    // 3

k = {key: "i", values: [h, i, j]} // 14



function addCumulativeValue (obj) {
  if(obj.value) {
    return obj.value;
  }
  
  obj.value = obj.values
    .map(o => addCumulativeValue(o))
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
}

addCumulativeValue(k);
k.value
```

Comment: You forgot to add a return statement. There's no async here... The `if` condition returns `true` on the first attempt and it returns the array!

    `if (obj.value) {`

The `obj.value` is truthy for non-empty arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't `return` the final `obj.value`:

```js
a={key:"a",value:1}// 1 b={key:"b",values:[a,a,a]}// 3 c={key:"c",values:[a,a]}// 2 d={key:"d",values:[a,a,a]}// 3 e={key:"e",values:[a,a]}// 2 f={key:"f",values:[a,a]}// 2 g={key:"g",values:[a]}// 1 h={key:"h",values:[a,b,c]}// 6 i={key:"i",values:[d,e]}// 5 j={key:"i",values:[f,g]}// 3 k={key:"i",values:[h,i,j]}// 14

function addCumulativeValue(obj) {
  if (obj.value) {
    return obj.value;
  }

  obj.value = obj.values
    .map(o => addCumulativeValue(o))
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    
  return obj.value;
}

addCumulativeValue(k);
console.log(k.value);
```

There are no async issues, you just forgot to `return` when following the recursion pattern in your recursive function.